# How to convert Webpage page or HTML url to pdf?

Tags: python, web-scraping, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, weasyprint

I am trying to Convert HTML page or HTML URL to a pdf which converts not just html but css as well and save it.I am Confused what should I use ( weasyprint, wkhtmltopdf or python pdfkit). Meanwhile I am using this code:

```
def ConvertToPdf(urltoConvert=None):
    import pdfkit
    pdfFormatOptions= {'page-size':'Letter', 'disable-forms':'','zoom': 1}
    pdfObject = None
    try:
        pdfkit.from_url('http://tdi.dartmouth.edu/', 'dart.pdf')
    except:
       Exception while converting"

        pass
    return pdfObject
if __name__ == "__main__":
  #  url ='http://tdi.dartmouth.edu/'
    ConvertToPdf()
```

And This code

```
import weasyprint
pdf = weasyprint.HTML('http://tdi.dartmouth.edu/').write_pdf()
len(pdf)
file('dart.pdf', 'w').write(pdf)
```

But all in vain please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and use:
**https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit**

It has a function for saving the CSS as well

```
You can specify external CSS files when converting files or strings using css option.

Warning This is a workaround for this bug in wkhtmltopdf. You should try –user-style-sheet option first.

# Single CSS file
css = 'example.css'
pdfkit.from_file('file.html', options=options, css=css)

# Multiple CSS files
css = ['example.css', 'example2.css']
pdfkit.from_file('file.html', options=options, css=css)
```

Comment: For every website do we have to specify CSS file before..? I mean if we are automatic the script to simply convert every html page to pdf with css. How we gonna know css file.??

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'res.pdf')
```

Also, another solution might be to make screenshot via selenium and compose .pdf from those images. But, it's pretty dirty.

Comment: Does convert CSS as well ? And How do I save it ?

Comment: Please help me with this.